# How to clear screen in Windows command prompt window with a hotkey?

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line, autohotkey

I have searched a lot to find a way (keyboard shortcut) to clear the screen of the console window of *cmd* on Windows 10. I tried <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> and <kbd>ESC</kbd>, but nothing worked for me and I didn't find any satisfied solution.

Thanks a lot for the *AutoHotkey* script.
I modified the script to input *Python* script to clear the screen when using `scrapy shell` like that

```
Send from os import system{Enter}
Send cls = lambda: system)'cls'({Enter}
Send cls)({Enter}
```

It worked well but I noticed the value `0` at the top of the window.

The console window after execution of *AutoHotkey* script with `█` as blinking caret symbol.

```
0
>>> █
```

How can I remove that zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way of clear window in command prompt is typing: cls + enter

**Ecs** is a key to exit input of command prompt, it does noting on clear window

**Ctrl + L and Ctrl + K** are not correct short key in Linux command prompt. If you really want to make it a short cut key of cls, you can use AutoHotKey to write a short script

```html
; -------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Cntr-L should clear screen
; -------------------------------------------------------------------------
#IfWinActive ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass
^L::
Send cls{Enter}
return

#IfWinActive
```

Official website of autohotkey: https://www.autohotkey.com/

Windows 10 + python 3.9 clear command prompt script:
import os
os.system('cls')

Answer (score 0):

To the last; I apologize for my student error, which if you consider spending 4 hours on testing suggested Python ways to clear the screen you might be less critical. And when one of those failed methods worked just once, because of some MS Windows bug, was almost as irritating to me.

To the code posting help. Thank you a page-full of nicely formatted content.

Below samples are for Windows 11 64 bit only, running on a Gigabyte/AMD/Corsair newly built PC.

First what worked using a dos command console to load Python by typing the word 'python' and pressing enter.

```
import os
clr_scr = lambda: os.system('cls') # cls is a ms dos command 
clr_scr()
```

Next, what did not yield any error, but does not clear the screen.

```
import os
def clr_scr():
    os.system('cls')
    # Call to Windows to clear screen
    clr_scr()
```

Thanks for the help, have a great rest of your weekend.